# Problem with spyder Type error: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, spyder

After ran the code on spyder a lot of times, this error appeared.

'tuple' object is not callable

```
X=float(input("¿Cual es el valor del cateto opuesto?: "))
Y=float(input("¿Cual es el valor del cateto adyacente?: "))
H=((X)**2+(Y)**2)**0.5
print(H)
```

And this appeared on the Terminal

```
runfile('D:/Docente Catedra Udea/Algoritmos y Programacion/2018- 
2/Estudiantes/Practicas/Practica_3/Calculo de la Hipotenusa DANNA VALENTINA 
VILLAMIL GONZÁLEZ.py', wdir='D:/Docente Catedra Udea/Algoritmos y 
Programacion/2018-2/Estudiantes/Practicas/Practica_3')

¿Cual es el valor del cateto opuesto?: 1

¿Cual es el valor del cateto adyacente?: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-19-ccf4414dc7a2>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('D:/Docente Catedra Udea/Algoritmos y Programacion/2018- 
2/Estudiantes/Practicas/Practica_3/Calculo de la Hipotenusa DANNA VALENTINA 
VILLAMIL GONZÁLEZ.py', wdir='D:/Docente Catedra Udea/Algoritmos y 
Programacion/2018-2/Estudiantes/Practicas/Practica_3')

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "D:/Docente Catedra Udea/Algoritmos y Programacion/2018- 
2/Estudiantes/Practicas/Practica_3/Calculo de la Hipotenusa DANNA VALENTINA 
VILLAMIL GONZÁLEZ.py", line 11, in <module>
print(H)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Any advice on how to solve this would be welcome.

Comment: The error is basically implying that print isn't a function but a tuple. Have you by any chance overwritten print with a tuple somewhere?  
e.g. check the `type(print)` - is it a method / function ?

Comment: What Marvin said. You probably accidentally did something like `print=(a,b)`. The simple solution is to restart your Python interpreter.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for you answer. The problem is related with the function print() because the variable H contains the value of the equation. So, what can I do?

Comment: @MarvinTaschenberger type(print) is a tuple

Comment: You need to find where your code assigned that tuple to the name `print` and fix that.